Not found the Classes Activiti version 6.0.0
I am migrating the Activiti framework from the verion 5.22.0 to 6.0.0, I couldnt found the below classes in the version 6.0.0
ArrayELResolver,
BeanELResolver,
CompositeELResolver,
ELResolver,
ListELResolver,
and MapELResolver
Can someone please help me to get the how i can migrate them in the application ?
I just want to know where i can found the above mentioned classes in the version 6.0.0 Activiti
